# Is it possible to disable field but apply control with reactive form in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form in my application and I display a field which is dynamically and asynchronously filled. I want to disable this field but I want to apply the control because my form is only valid if this value is not empty (required).

I have used this code :

```
this.myForm.get(myField).disable()
```

In my page the field is disable, but unfortunately the control is no longer applied. Actually when I read the documentation it is pretty normal :

> Disables the control. This means the control will be exempt from
>   validation checks and excluded from the aggregate value of any parent.
>   Its status is DISABLED.
>
> If the control has children, all children will be disabled to maintain
>   the model.

So is there a way to disable my field and keep the control active with reactive form ? Should I disable my field manually with disable attribute in my template ?

Comment: I have set `disabled` attribute in my template. It works but I think it is not clean because it bypasses reactive form system. I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: That seems fair enough to me, although is there a reason you want to use `disabled` instead of `readonly` ? By the way, there is an open issue that might be of interest to you, although it's open and waiting for input from the team :
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11447